# Has Microsoft Deprecated GFlags and UMDH?

Tags: windows-8, windows-7, windows-vista, gflags, umdh

In Windows Vista I found UMDH to be very helpful, but I can't find it for Windows 7/8, has Microsoft deprecated GFlags and UMDH? If so is there a way that I can get a log of the allocations on the heap by call stack in a Windows 7/8 approved tool?

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft hasn't deprecated GFlags and UMDH.  It is still included as part of "Debugging Tools for Windows".  You can get it as part of the Windows Software Development kit (go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891 to get the version compatible with Windows 7 and 8).

Once the "Debugging Tools for Windows" installation completes, GFlags and UMDH will be located in the installation directory (e.g. at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.x\Debuggers\x86").